# CI session misbehaving

Tags: codeigniter, session

i have a system in which there is a function which basically does is check for some basic features that function is called in every controller for security.let me show you the code first

```
public function check_unique_id_from_db_for_secuity(){

        $needle=base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
        $haystack=$this->User_model->get_all_unique_ids();
        $data2=array();
        foreach($haystack as $key=>$value){
            array_push($data2,$value['unique_id']);
        }
        $status="";
        if(in_array($needle,$data2))
        {
            $status= "Exist";
        }
        else
        {
            $status= "Not Exist";
        }
        if($status=="Not Exist") {
            redirect("User/logout");
        }
        echo $this->session->userdata('user');
        if ($this->session->userdata('user') !== FALSE) {

        } else {
            redirect("User/logout");
        }
    }
```

now what happens in the end of function the i have validated session as well. now this logic of session works perfectly fine in firefox! but **webkit** browsers such as chrome and opera it doesn't work now the really awkward thing is if i echo the session value i am receiving the correct value and the code starts working just fine but when i remove the echo the user is logged out.

Comment: Have you set the session save path in config.php  don't leave it NULL

Comment: yes i have already by $config['sess_save_path']= BASEPATH.'ci_sessions';